# Best practice for uploading images to a web server

Tags: javascript, web, server

My target from this question is to know what is the best approach for uploading image(s) to a server? and why?

By passing into several web forms contain upload image for some reason (profile, post...), I noticed that by selecting the image, is directly uploaded to the server before submitting the form! Why isn't uploaded while the user is submitting? Where is the image uploaded and what if the user discarded the post? Let suppose the images are uploaded to temp directory after submitting, the images should moves to non temp directory, so why the developers are mostly using this approach what is the target? it's for the security wise? too many questions...

Any one can declare or provide me an useful article that answer or explain the case above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most forms will make use of some combination of front and backend functions to check if the uploaded image fits certain criterias. It is possible to wait for the submit action and that would probably relieve some work from the server.

Most forms do this check on upload because it's easier for the users. It's really common for users to give up on a form after a submit fail, so it's good practice to validate as soon as possible, in order to allow the user to fix things right away.

Answer (score 4):

**Let take a simple scenario.**
You have 200kb/s net connection and went to facebook or any other site and need to fill a form. The form requires an image. You selected an **image of 10MB size**. Assuming the image will be loaded when you submit the form, considering your internet speed, it may take **some time to complete the request.** This may increase even more if the website creates multiple sizes of the same image for showing on different size of the devices. During this process, many things can happen. For Ex: You may get annoyed and leave the website. In the end, **the website will lose a potential user.**

The above scenario **can be prevented by multiple ways** such as having an **image size restriction** on the client side or by just **warning user about the high image size**. But those options create a bad user experience and has a chance to lose a user. As an organization/website owner, **we do not want to lose any user.** We try to **create a good experience for the users** to come to our website so that they can visit again and again. By starting the upload process before, we are reducing the time taking to submit the form and thus creating a better user experience.

Now, the above scenario is simple. Now you may ask what if the user doesn't complete the form. In such a case, the image uploaded can be used for other purposes such as training the organization's ML/AI(if they have such functionalities) or any other purpose depending upon the organization. There can be a number of factors that can go into making such a technical decision. Is the website catering to mobile users? Does the organization use the image for any other purpose also other purposes also?

**In Short: It depends**